# Laravel 7 error - SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'first_name' cannot be null

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, laravel

I am trying to submit form data to a database using Jquery Ajax, but I get the error message. It seems like the values of the input fields are not received at the Controller end, which is why it is not sent to the database for storing. Here is a  brief description of what I intent to do :-

1. A user opts to sign up.
2. The Signup page opens (Let's call it **Form 1**)
3. The user fills up data in **Form 1**
4. If there is any error message like empty field or invalid format, it is displayed under the respective input field in **Form 1**
5. If there are no error messages, then the user is redirected to a new form(let's call this **Form 2**) , with all the prefilled data from **Form 1**.
6. If the user clicks "submit", the data (from **Form 2**) is sent to the Controller using Ajax where it is stored in a database with a *Sweet Alert* message

However, it seems like the data is not properly sent to the controller ,which is why I am getting the error.

The codes are given below

The blade of ***Form 2***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

      <!-- CSRF Token Meta Added -->
      <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Ajax script -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>


    <!-- Sweet Alert -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>


    </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Navigation Bar --> 
   <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark navbar-fixed-top">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index">User Info</a>
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
    </li>

    
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right ">
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="new_user"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="login"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
    </ul>

  
</nav>
    </div>
  </div>

 <div class="text-center pt-3">
<p style="color:red">For safety,Do Not hit the back button or refresh the page</p>
<p style="color:red">Use the buttons given in the form below</p>
</div>

<form class="form-group" id="new_user_form" method="post"  autocomplete="off">
 <div class="row  m-5 p-5 bg-warning text-white">
     <div class="col">
<div class="form-group">
  @csrf
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" id="csrf" value="{{Session::token()}}">
 <label for="fname">First Name:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" name="first_name" value="{{$first_name}}" readonly >
</div>
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="lname">Last Name:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" id="last_name" value="{{$last_name}}" readonly>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="email">Email/Username:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" value="{{$email}}" readonly>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" value="{{$password}}" readonly>
</div>

  <div class="form-group">
 <label for="mobno">Mobile Number:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mobno" id="mobno" value="{{$mobno}}" readonly>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="dob">Date of Birth(in YYYY-MM-DD):</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dob" id="dob" value="{{$dob}}" readonly>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="gender">Gender:</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="gender" id="gender" value="{{$gender}}" readonly>

 </div>
  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="address">Address:</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="address" id="address" readonly>{{$address}}</textarea>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="country">Country:</label>
 <input name="country" class="form-control" id="countrylist" value="{{$country}}" readonly>
</div>

 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="dt">Date and Time of Submission:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dt" id="dt" value=@php date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata"); echo date("Y-m-d,H:i:s ") @endphp readonly>
</div>
<div class="form-group text-center">
<!-- <a href="{{url('recheck_form')}}"/><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2 text-center" onclick="store_using_ajax()">Submit</button> -->
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2 text-center" id="submit_form">Submit</button>
</div>
<div class="form-group text-center ">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><a href="new_user">Cancel</a></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning "><a href="">Edit</a></button>
</div>

</div>

</div>

</form>

</div>   
 


<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#submit_form').click(function (e){

       e.preventDefault(); //Prevents the form from submitting

          // var  first_name      =    $('#first_name').val(),
          // var last_name        =    $('#last_name').val(),
          // var email            =    $('#email').val(),
          // var password         =    $('#password').val(),
          // var mobno            =    $('#mobno').val(),
          // var dob              =    $('#dob').val(),
          // var gender           =    $('#gender').val(),
          // var address          =    $('#address').val(),
          // var dt               =    $('#dt').val(),
 
       /*Ajax Request Header setup*/
   $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      }
      });  

     $.ajax({
       type:'POST',
       url: "submit-form" ,
       cache: false,
       processData: false,
         contentType: false,
       
        // data: $('#new_user_form').serialize(),
        data: {

           // _token             :    $("#csrf").val(),
           // first_name         :    first_name,  
           // last_name          :    last_name,  
           // email              :    email  ,
           // password           :    password  ,  
           // mobno              :    mobno ,  
           // dob                :    dob  ,
           // gender             :    gender  ,
           // address            :    address   ,  
           // dt                 :    dt   ,  
            

          '_token'             :    $("#csrf").val(),
         'first_name'         :    $('#first_name').val(),
          'last_name'         :    $('#last_name').val(),
          'email'             :    $('#email').val(),
          'password'           :    $('#password').val(),
          'mobno'              :    $('#mobno').val(),
          'dob'                 :     $('#dob').val(),
          'gender'              :     $('#gender').val(),
          'address'              :       $('#address').val(),
          'dt'                  :        $('#dt').val(),

        },
        dataType: 'JSON',

       success:function(data){
            swal({
         title: "Form Submitted Successfully!",
         text: "New User Registered !",
         icon: "success",
         button: "Okay",
         timer: 1500
       })
            setTimeout(function(){ window.location = "login-page"; }, 2000);
             


       },
       error: function(data){
       swal({
             title: "Error in submitting form",
             text: "Please try again later! ",
             icon: "warning",
            button: "Okay",
            });
            
             }
  });

   });
     });

 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

The Controller code for ***Form 2***

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Newuser;

class NewUserRegnController extends Controller
{
       public function submitNewRegn(Request $request){
     
    $r_first_name           =   $request->first_name;
    $r_last_name            =   $request->last_name;
    $r_email                =   $request->email;
    $r_password             =   Hash::make($request->password, [
                                     'memory' => '1024',
                                     'time' =>  '2',
                                     'threar' =>  '2',
                                    ]);
    // $confirm_password    =   $request->confirm_password;
    $r_mobno                =   $request->mobno;
    $r_dob              =   $request->dob;
    $r_gender           =   $request->gender;
    $r_address          =   $request->address;
    $r_country          =   $request->country;
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata"); 
    $r_time             =   date("Y-m-d,H:i:s ");

      // $users = new Newuser();
      // $users->first_name = $first_name; 
      // $users->last_name = $last_name; 
      // $users->email = $email; 
      // $users->password = $password; 
      // $users->mobno = $mobno; 
      // $users->dob = $dob; 
      // $users->gender = $gender; 
      // $users->address = $address; 
      // $users->country = $country; 
      // $users->TIME_STAMP = $time; 

      // $users->save();


    $act =  "INSERT";
    DB::select('CALL my_stored_procedures(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', array($act,0,$r_first_name,$r_last_name,$r_email,$r_password,$r_mobno,$r_dob,   $r_gender,$r_address,$r_country,$r_time));
   

  return response()->json(
            [
                'success' => true,
                'message' => 'Data inserted successfully'
            ]
        );


      }
}
```

Although I haven't used *_token* anywhere , I will be adding session and cookies in steps, since I am new to Laravel.  So, don't mind that.

Comment: You are using Model, did you added all column name on your model's `fillable` property?

Comment: Use data validation in back end code to avoid this kind of issues.

Comment: I was testing the code with model, but now I dont. @sta

Comment: @iamab.in Yes. I didnt use data validation in the blade

Comment: Fillable lets you specify which fields is mass-assignable in your model. Lets take the above example, you can do it by adding the special variable `$fillable` to the model. So in the model like : `protected $fillable = ['first_name', 'last_name'];`

Comment: You should use data validation in laravel code. Refer [this](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation)

Comment: Also make sure, data from form 1 is successfully added to form2

Comment: Nope. I removed the Model thing from the Controller and it still didn't work

Comment: @iamab.in I made sure that data is received from Form 1 to Form 2 properly, and also I used validation in form 1 itself. So, no need to validate again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1)
I'd suggest to have a look at the actual request received at the controller end; `dd($request)` as the first line in `submitNewRegn`

Step 2)
(as mentioned by iamab.in in comments) proceed to validate the contents of the submitted form the validation methods outlined [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation). The validation should match the typesetting in the database table (look at your migration file!)

This would look something like this:

```
request()->validate([
                'first_name' => 'required|min:3',
                'last_name' => 'required|min:2',
            ]);
```

Step 3)
Store in correct table in database

This could look something like this:

```
$user= User::create($attributes);
```